# How to disable fn + a shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, monterey

How do I disable the <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> shortcut?

When I press and release these, it makes the dock appear, highlights the TV icon in the dock, and defocusses the current window.

After I removed the TV.app icon from the dock, it now focusses the Finder icon.

How do I disable this entirely? I don't want <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to have any OS functionality.

I already tried System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys, set function to No Action, but that didn't change anything (and Press Globe to... is already "Do Nothing")

Comment: Sorry if this seems rather obvious, but why not just avoid pressing that shortcut key combo?

Comment: @Allan it's a common key combination in a game I play. For some reason I'd been able to play fine before years ago (mb fn+a is a recent macOS addition? I can't find out bout it online), but now I keep getting kicked out of the window and dying because the dock pops up out of nowhere

Comment: Just a thought…it’s probably better to remap the shortcut in the game rathe than try to remap a system wide shortcut.

Comment: From all your questions that basically center around using your Mac as a gaming machine, **you might have a strong question regarding using a Mac and macOS as a gaming platform**.  It will have to be ***objective*** in nature.   Maybe you could enumerate your issues (questions) and posit “given these issues (and possibly more) is Apple a good gaming platform?”  It would be a risky question (walking the line of being opinionated) but if you keep it objective, it might be a good one.

Comment: +1 to negate the down vote.  I’m not a gamer so it’s not applicable to me, but this is a valid question especially given that you disabled the `Fn` key.

Comment: I rolled back because this isn’t about Karabiner. It’s about modifier keys, disabling keys under macOS.

Comment: @Allan I thought maybe I can do some workaround, like sending the keys directly to the frontmost app, instead of allowing the OS to detect them. Karabiner is just a keyboard shortcut program I already have installed, wanted to signal I'd be up for third-party solutions

Comment: The tags are for what the question is about, not potential solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you are up for a third-party solution, I have successfully blocked macOS 13.x from responding to fn+a by using a tool called [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/):

Keyboard shortcuts / press '+' on the bottom to add a trigger, press fn+a, select 'Click here & select action', select 'no action'.

[image: configuration to macOS from responding to fn+A]

Note: The application is not free and it might be overkill for just this use case if you can find a way to accomplish this with Karabiner. I'm not affiliated with the developer.