# What are the function key shortcuts?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, monterey

When you press and release the function key and some letters keys at the same time, it has some special macOS actions. I can't find anything official about these online.

What are they? How can I control and hopefully disable them all?

Comment: I don't know how to disable them all, but one can disable fn key itself (Systen Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Modifier keys -> Globe key -> No action).

Comment: @AivarPaalberg - this question is a direct [yet unlinked] follow-up to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/460019/how-to-disable-fn-a-shortcut

Answer (score 7):

The <kbd>Fn/</kbd> (Function/Globe Key) shortcuts don't seem to be documented anywhere. The only way to disable the shortcuts is to disable the Fn key entirely (using `hidutil`) and that's not a viable solution.  It appears the documentation folks at Apple have inadvertently omitted this info.

Since these shortcuts aren't documented anywhere, I did a little experimentation and came up with this list of shortcuts for reference.  Activate the shortcut by pressing and holding the <kbd>Fn/</kbd> along with the associated key/letter.  See below.

| Shortcut | Action |
| --- | --- |
| A | Activate Dock |
| C | Activate Control Center |
| D | Activate Dictation |
| E | Emoji Viewer |
| F | Toggle Fullscreen |
| H | View/Hide Desktop |
| M | Move focus to Menubar |
| N | Notification Center |
| Q | Quick Notes |
| Del | Delete Character to right of cursor. Same as <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> <sup>†</sup> |
| <kbd>↑</kbd> | Scroll Up 1 page <sup>†</sup> |
| <kbd>↓</kbd> | Scroll Down 1 page <sup>†</sup> |
| <kbd>←</kbd> | Scroll to beginning of document <sup>†</sup> |
| <kbd>→</kbd> | Scroll to end of document <sup>†</sup> |

<sup>(Tested in Ventura only)</sup>

---

<sup>†</sup> Included here for completeness only.  This shortcut can be found on Apple's website:  [Mac Keyboard Shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201236)

Comment: Do you know when all the letter ones were added?

Comment: At least Ventura.  My other machine is Catalina and I don't believe they are there (can test over the weekend). I don't have Big Sur or Mojave  installed anywhere to verify this.  Since it's not even documented, I wouldn't know where to find this definitive info other than testing.

Comment: Only the 'old' ones already documented work on Mojave [either that or only if you have a key with a globe on it. I have no way to differentiate, next newest Mac has globe AND Ventura.]

Comment: On my machine I discovered following fn shortcuts in Safari: fn+x closes active tab/window, fn+d scroll down, fn+u scroll up

Comment: @theonlygusti I'm on Monterey (12.6.5) and the letter ones work here.